# PDO Fetch shows results twice

Tags: php, database, pdo

First of all I am new to PDO, just started working with it a week ago.

I'm trying to load the website configuration out of the database, and echo it on the page, however, any table/field result displays twice while I only need one.

This is the code

```
function config() {
    global $db;
    try {
        $sql = "SELECT id, name FROM config";
        $stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->execute();
        $row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

        echo $row['id'];



    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        echo '<pre>';
        echo 'Line: ' . $e->getLine() . '<br />';
        echo 'File: ' . $e->getFile() . '<br />';
        echo 'Error Message: ' . $e->getMessage();
        echo '</pre>';
    }
}
```

Now when I echo the $row['id']; or $row['name']; it will display twice on the page, while it only needs to be shown once.

Is there anything that I am doing wrong?

Comment: It looks fine from here.  Are you calling `config()` twice?

Comment: Maybe you call `config()` twice?

Comment: Silly me, That had to be it, I forgot I had $this->config(); in the __construct function, and one on a different page to load the class. Thank you for your quick response. :)